# Image of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ under Veronese embedding; a conicc

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

> Consider the Veronese surface $S$ defined by the map:
>   $$\phi: \mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^5$$
>   where $\phi(x_0,x_1,x_2)=(x_0^2,x_0x_1,x_0x_2,x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2)$.

The problem asks to show that a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is mapped to a conic in $\mathbb{P^5}$

**I will use the following notation** The definition of the Veronese map will be taken from the question above. I will denote the coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^{5}$  by $[z_{0}:\ldots:z_{5}]$ and the coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ by $[x_{0}:x_{1}: x_{2}]$.

**Claim** The Veronese surface is cut out by three quadrics:
$$C_{1}:  z_{0}z_{3} - z_{1}^{2} = 0$$
$$C_{2}: z_{0}z_{5} -z_{2}^{2}= 0 $$
$$C_{3}: z_{3}z_{5} - z_{4}^{2} = 0. $$

Suppose a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is defined by $ax_0+bx_1+cx_2=0$. So can the image of the line in $\mathbb{P}^5$ be thought as the intersection of $S$ and something else? I have the following questions:

- How do we show that it is a conic?

I posted this question 14 hours ago didn't have many views and didn't get any answer, for the bounty I think I have to wait more days. So I am reposting it hoping that it will reach to other mathematicians and hopefully I will get some answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Image of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ under Veronese embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168006/image-of-a-line-in-mathbbp2-under-veronese-embedding)

Comment: See the question,  it is mentioned there S is the Veronese surface.

Comment: See the lower comment where I said that I am reposting the question.  You can answer under any of the questions.

Comment: It’s considered rather bad form to repost a question less than a day later just because there’s been no activity on the original.

Comment: Ohh ok. I am sorry. Can anyone please give an answer or a hint? Except the one in the last post

Comment: Can anyone please give me some more hint? Any plane can indeed be transformed into $x_0=0$ by rotation but what will be the effect on the conic. Again is there any other direct way to find out?